# How to get SQL Server's TOTAL I/O Statistics with Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

From the link:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/2244381/Examining-SQL-Servers-IO-Statistics.htm

I got the query

```
-- Take a look at raw I/O Statistics
SELECT @@TOTAL_READ [Total Reads]
     , @@TOTAL_WRITE as [Total Writes]
     , CAST(@@IO_BUSY as FLOAT) * @@TIMETICKS / 1000000.0 as [IO Sec]
GO

(Results)

Total Reads Total Writes IO Sec  
----------- ------------ ----------- 
      85336       322109      25.375
```

How do I get this but this time I can have date filters?
i.e.

```
where
xDate between Date1 and Date2
```

?

@Note :

This is different from question [How to find out SQL Server table's read/write statistics with Date Filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912343/how-to-find-out-sql-server-tables-read-write-statistics-with-date-filter) as this is the TOTAL and the other is per TABLE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out SQL Server table's read/write statistics with Date Filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912343/how-to-find-out-sql-server-tables-read-write-statistics-with-date-filter)

Comment: @RichBenner this one is total and the other is per table

Comment: All the statistics are current. No, there is no way to provide date range filter to any of this kind of statistics.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to take periodic snapshots and compare them over time to be able to do what you're asking for.